# How to calculate Bayes factor for conditional probability?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, likelihood-ratio, bayes-factors

I have a data set of 1000 drug-effect pairs. I am trying to identify which drug is most likely given the observed effect.

My original approach was to calculate $P\left(d_j | e_i\right)$ for each drug $d_j$ and effect $e_i$, create an empiric probability distribution by resampling, estimate $p$-values, and identify all pairs that passed the Benjamini-Yekutieli threshold.

But, applying a correction for multiple hypothesis and frequentist testing to a Bayesian statistic seemed off.

On further reading I discovered Bayes' factor, but I don't really understand how to calculate it.

For each drug-effect pair $\left(d_j, e_i\right)$ I have two hypotheses:

1. $H_0 \Rightarrow p\left(d_j\right) = p\left(d_j | e_i\right)$
2. $H_\alpha \Rightarrow p\left(d_j\right) \neq p\left(d_j | e_i\right)$

I assume $p\left(H_0\right) = p\left(H_\alpha\right)$ and $p\left(H_0\right) + p\left(H_\alpha\right) = 1$.

Bayes Factor = $\frac{\textrm{posterior odds}}{\textrm{posterior odds}} \Rightarrow \frac{p\left(H_\alpha | \textrm{D}\right)}{p\left(H_0 | \textrm{D}\right)}\Big / \frac{p\left(H_\alpha\right)}{p\left(H_0\right)}$

I don't know how to calculate the numerator of this fraction. 
One can switch the terms with Bayes' theorem, but I don't know how to calculate $p\left(\textrm{D} | H_O\right)$ either.

My data are of form of matrices where the $ij$th element indicates the number of times drug $i$ and effect $j$ were reported together.

As a secondary question, I wonder why it seems that I wouldn't have to correct Bayes Factor for multiple comparisons.

Comment: What is a drug-effect pair? What is the model for how such a pair is generated?

Comment: @mef a drug-effect pair is an ordered pair $\left(x,y\right)$ where x comes from a list of drugs and y a list of effects. A pair is generated (empirically) by counting the number of times an effect y is reported after using drug x. This model simplifies by ignoring the interactions between drugs.

Comment: So a given drug can be used more than once? How many times is each drug used? And a given drug can have more than one effect? Is there a limit on the how many effects? BTW, how many drugs are there and how many effects? What are the dimensions of your matrix? The entries of the matrix are nonnegative integers? What's the minimum? What's the maximum?